# SQL Filter Resultset in WHERE clause

Tags: sql, firebird

I have got a problem with a Resultset-Filter.

My SQL query gives a list that looks like:

```
LOAD_NR -------- REASON_ID
399              19
399              20  
399              21
399              22  
400              19
400              20
401              20
402              20
```

Now I would like to have a list of Load numbers which have e.g. Reason_ID = 19 AND Reason_ID = 20.
In this Example this would be: 399 and 400.

I'm using a Firebird database.

Comment: What is your sql query?@SWYM

Comment: With SQL queries you should always tag the DBMS you are using. For example some DBMS feature `INTERSECT` whereas others don't. (That would be: `select load_nr from mytable where reason_id = 19 intersect select load_nr from mytable where reason_id = 20`.)

Comment: It's not an easy one, it contains a lot of joins.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT LOAD_NR
FROM mytable
WHERE REASON_ID IN (19, 20)
GROUP BY LOAD_NR
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT REASON_ID) = 2
```

Comment: Thanks, it's not a complete solution for my problem, but it gave me a good hint how I can solve it ;)
edit: too bad I need 4 more reputation to vote up you posting :(

Answer (score 0):

You need to select all values that satisfy both conditions, so you need to check existence separately:

```sql
select distinct load_nr
from thetable a
where exists (select 1 from thetable where load_nr = a.load_nr and reason_id = 19)
and exists (select 1 from thetable where load_nr = a.load_nr and reason_id = 20)
```

Alternatively your could use [`ANY` (or `SOME`)](https://www.firebirdsql.org/file/documentation/html/en/refdocs/fblangref25/firebird-25-language-reference.html#fblangref25-commons-quant-anysome), but that will likely have worse performance:

```sql
select distinct load_nr
from thetable a
where 19 = any (select reason_id from thetable where load_nr = a.load_nr)
and 20 = any (select reason_id from thetable where load_nr = a.load_nr)
```